# Process.Start() throws Permission denied error in linux container while using docker desktop from windows host machine

Tags: linux, windows, exception, permissions, containers

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): An error occurred trying to start process '/home/app/SE.IA.MAF.ToolBroker/SE.IA.MAF.ToolBroker.exe' with working directory '/home/app/SE.IA.MAF.ToolBroker'. Permission denied
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at SE.IA.MAF.AppRegistry.CLI.Utils.AppLauncher.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<TryToLaunchApplicationAsync>b__0() in C:\Software Experience\mfe-shell-common\app-infra\arc\AppRegistry-CLI\Utils\App\AppLauncher.cs:line 46
```

**Dockerfile used**:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY ["./ARC-New", "/home/app"]
EXPOSE 5411
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "arc.dll"]
```

Tried to run container as a non root user, but exception persists.

Comment: Same issue for me. Any solutions? It passed 2 months.

Comment: Hi @EmirKılınç
 The reason behind for me was, the parent dll (arc.dll for me) was trying to execute multiple exe on Linux environment. But on Linux exe is not supported, only dll is supported. Thus need to execute only dll.